# I can't update create-react-app, any suggestion?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

[SS of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CPYa.png)

Hi, I've a problem trying to update this, I tried everything like a uninstall, install, cache clean, with yarn, etc, but when I checked the version still in 2.1.8

Comment: Have you tried flagging the version, as in `npm i -g create-react-app@3.4.0` ?

Answer (score 2):

I've got it :D

I tried the answers but I still have the same problem, so I followed these steps on my terminal:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

which create-react-app
> /usr/local/bin/create-react-app

rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app

npx create-react-app app_name --template typescript
```

thanks everyone for your answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use 'npx' instead of 'npm'

```
npx create-react-app AppName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever installed the create-react-app package globally you'll need to remove that, it will supercede local versions:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then you can install whatever version you'd like with whatever package manager you'd like, such as:

```
npm install create-react-app
```